# Как расшифровать сообщение

Tags: шифрование

Есть сообщение, зашифрованное шифром подстановки. Нужно определить зашифрованную строку.
Я новичок в криптоанализе. Могли бы сказать, как можно расшифровать подобное сообщение? Какой есть специальный подход к подобным задачам или стандартные шифры, которые стоит сразу пробовать? Может здесь нужно работать с битами?
(возможно в задаче нужен python)
Попробовал шифр Цезаря - не сработало.
Само сообщение:

```
 ыэахцтс чсгючцечдс чцаазч ыфтднсбвчцгэтъечяагднсдебыъ м
```

и аналогичное сообщение (тоже по шифру подстановки):

```
^яЬј>^џї^ЭѕЭЭЭ^яЬј>^џї^ЭЅњјЬЅЭњЬјј>}Ѕј\>^ј}^^]ќ\>ј|њќЭЬЅЭ\јь^џэЭ<]ј
```

Comment: Тут `ыэахцтс чсгючцечдс чцаазч` исходное сообщени, а тут `^яЬј>^џї^ЭѕЭЭЭ^яЬј>^џї^ЭЅњјЬЅЭњЬ` результат?

Comment: Это 2 результата, 2 разных сообщения, но оба по шифру подстановки. Как не имея ключа можно получить исходное сообщение каждого шифра?

Comment: Слишком короткое сообщение. Было бы длинное, можно было бы по частотам символов что-то предположить. А тут что - перебирать все варианты подстановок? Это почти нереально. Сочетания букв ещё есть частые, можно через них, но тоже сомнительно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я сейчас добавил полностью сообщения, обновите. Не понимаю почему в первый раз они урезались. Самый частый символ - "ч" (7 раз). потом "с" и пробел по 5 раз.

Comment: Всё-равно маловато, но можете попробовать посчитать частоты и подставить соответственно частоте буквы из предполагаемого языка. Где-то тут уже обсуждались подобные вопросы, там было интересно.

Comment: Второе выглядит как результат прочтения в неправильной кодировке

Comment: @Alexey Ten попробовал открыть его как файл через питон, в utf-8 кодировке открыл то же самое, а в кодировке windows-1251 вообще ничего не вывел, нет сообщения

Comment: Шифр замены не равен шифру Цезаря. А вот шифр цезаря – это именно шифр замены. Как так? А очень просто: шифр Цезаря – разновидность шифра замены. С битами работать не надо, так шифры битовых операций – самостоятельный класс шифров. Шифр же замены заменяет именно символы. Есть исходный символ, он заменяется другим, причём, никакие два символа не могут одним и тем же ключом заменяться на один и тот же. Уже из-за этого количество возможных ключей равно факториалу количества символов в алфавите.

Comment: Вскрыть ключ прямым подбором можно только в том случае, если в ключе меньше информации, чем в сообщении. Про взлавыемость частотным анализом не скажу, но ключ ещё может меняться при переходе к следующему символу, тогда частоты будут искажены. Задача может быть решена только в частном, но не в общем случае.

Answer (score 2):

Анализируем фразу

```
ыэахцтс чсгючцечдс чцаазч ыфтднсбвчцгэтъечяагднсдебыъ м
```

- Для начала подсчитаем количество вхождений каждого символа в фразу и подсчитаем его частоту вхождения
- Затем на основании [данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) о частотности букв русского языка, для самых распространенных букв, сделаем предположение о том, что это за буквы
- При этом заметим, что в сообщении две буквы `a` идут подряд. Очень вероятно, что это буква `н`

Теперь все это представим в таблице

| Буква | Количество | Частота, % | Вариант |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ы | 3 | 5.45 |  |
| э | 2 | 3.64 |  |
| а | 4 | 7.27 | а, е, и, **Н**, т |
| х | 1 | 1.82 |  |
| ц | 4 | 7.27 | а, е, и, н, т |
| т | 3 | 5.45 |  |
| с | 5 | 9.09 | а, е, *и*, о |
| Space | 4 | 7.27 | а, е, и, н, т |
| ч | 7 | 12.73 | Space, о |
| г | 3 | 5.45 |  |
| ю | 1 | 1.82 |  |
| е | 3 | 5.45 |  |
| д | 4 | 7.27 | а, е, и, н, т |
| з | 1 | 1.82 |  |
| ф | 1 | 1.82 |  |
| н | 2 | 3.64 |  |
| б | 2 | 3.64 |  |
| в | 1 | 1.82 |  |
| ъ | 2 | 3.64 |  |
| я | 1 | 1.82 |  |
| м | 1 | 1.82 |  |

А теперь попробуем заменить эти буквы в исходном сообщении и будем смотреть, что будет получаться

Comment: У ТС первый символ пробельный, если это не отступ случайный.